# Unexpected token ILLEGAL in concatenated CSS file

Tags: css, google-chrome, gulp, stylus

I'm getting the following error in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

At the start of my concatenated CSS file:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600")
```

This line ends up on its own, and it's specifically this line that throws the error:

[image]

I've had a look around and it seems this error *should* relate to invisible characters making their way into the code. Unfortunately in my case that doesn't *seem* to be true. I've even deleted this portion of code and re-written it by hand to make sure - no difference.

I use Stylus (with gulp) and the resulting compile is naturally what throws the error - is this maybe an issue with gulp-stylus? I've looked at the compiled code and can't track down any invisible characters there either…

Does anything else throw this error?

Answer (score 13):

The error implies you are trying to load the style sheet with `<script>` instead of `<link rel=stylesheet>`.

CSS is not JavaScript and can't be treated as such.

Comment: Afraid not:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dist/all.min.css" />`

Comment: @NathanHornby — Nothing stopping you having an incorrect `<script>` too.

Comment: Well my script declarations also look fine - and I imagine if the issue were there it wouldn't flag it on the first line of my CSS file…

Comment: @NathanHornby — It would if it was being told to load the CSS file as a `<script>`.

Comment: Um, no it doesn't. The only reference I can find for that error is for invisible characters - as stated in the question.

Comment: Loading that CSS with a link element — http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/31784650/link.html — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Loading that CSS with a script element — http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/31784650/script.html — gives the exact error message you screenshoted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to say - I've stated it clearly enough - the CSS is not being loaded in via a script element. I think I would be able to tell.

Comment: Have you opened the source in your browser and clicked on the links of all your script elements to make sure they contain what you think they should contain?

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting that line to see if it makes the error message going away? Does doing so give you a similar error message on the next line? Does adding `alert("JS");` give you a similar error or does it load an alert window?

Comment: Ah sheet - you were half right, typo in my gulp file was creating the bloody issue - in a similar way to what you describe, but harder to spot :/ Issue an edit to your answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Cheers - and thanks for your persistence! I thought you were going mad :p

Comment: These errors sneak up on you when using WP. It's the difference between wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script. This kicked my butt for a good 3 hours. Stupid silly mistakes.